# Include() does not load relationships in query. They are only filled on collection.load() or unrelated query of the other table

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm not getting the `student.StudentPublished` filled when calling my endpoint. Only if calling a query on `AContext.StudentPublished` or using `Collection.Load()` do I get any data filled for the relationship. Why isn't this join created with entity framework?

Setup of context:

```
public partial class AContext : DbContext
{
    public AContext(DbContextOptions<AContext> options): base(options) { }

    public virtual DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<StudentPublished> StudentPublished { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new StudentConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new StudentPublishedConfiguration());

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }        
}
```

In student configuration Configure(...):

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Student> builder)
{
    builder.ToTable("student");
    builder.HasKey(e => e.ReferenceNumber);
    builder.Property(e => e.ReferenceNumber)
        .HasColumnName("id");

    builder.Property(e => e.FirstName)
        .HasColumnName("name")

    builder.Property(e => e.LastName)
        .HasColumnName("surname")
        .IsUnicode(false);

    builder.HasMany(e => e.StudentPublished).WithOne(sp => sp.Student).HasForeignKey(sp => sp.ReferenceNumber);
}
```

StudentPublished configuration:

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<StudentPublished> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Student_Publicised");

        builder.Property(e => e.ReferenceNumber)
            .HasColumnName("ref");
        builder.Property(e => e.Ok)
            .HasColumnName("IsOK");
        builder.Property(e => e.PeriodId)
            .HasColumnName("fk_PeriodId");
        builder.Property(e => e.PkId)
            .HasColumnName("pk_ID");

        builder.HasKey(sp => sp.PkId);
        builder.HasAlternateKey(sp => sp.PeriodId);
        builder.HasAlternateKey(sp => sp.ReferenceNumber);

        builder.HasOne(e => e.Student).WithMany(s => s.StudentPublished).HasForeignKey(e => e.ReferenceNumber);

    }
```

Student Model:

```
public partial class Student
{
    public int ReferenceNumber { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public List<StudentPublished> StudentPublished { get; set; }
}
```

StudentPublished Model:

```
public partial class StudentPublished
{
    public int ReferenceNumber { get; set; }
    public bool Ok { get; set; }
    public Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

Endpoint:

```
 public IActionResult Get(int id)
 {
    var student = dataContext.Students.Include(s=>s.StudentPublished).FirstOrDefault(s=>s.ReferenceNumber == id);

    return Ok(student);
}
```

Comment: What is the primary key of StudentPublished table or database object? Also, could you try modifying your Student class to include a constructor as public Student() { StudentPublished = new List<StudentPublished>(); }

Comment: @sam, I Updated the the question with the other configuration and tried the constructor but the constructor does nothing more than give a empty list instead of null in the endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after much banging of my head against the keyboard I tried using the nuget `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies` and enabling Lazy loading in the configuration of context at startup. Why this should make `include` load eagerly in the correct way, I have no idea, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try change method in the controller to:

```
public IActionResult Get(int id)
{
   var student = dataContext.Students
      .Where(s => s.ReferenceNumber == id)
      .Include(s => s.StudentPublished)
      .FirstOrDefault();

   return Ok(student);
}
```